# Dynamic Conditional Statement

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I want to create dynamic conditional statement in java
following are my expression in file,There are hundreds of expression and they keep on changing

```
0001|((condition1 == 100) && ((condition2 == 1) || (condition2 == 2) || (condition2 == 3)) && (condition3 > 74))
0002|((condition1 == 100) && ((condition2 == 1) || (condition2 == 2) || (condition2 == 3)) && (condition3 > 59) && ((condition4 == 3) || (condition5 > 30)))
```

These expression are hardcoded in my class.

```
if(condition1==100 && ((condition2 == 1) || (condition2 == 2) || (condition2 == 3))){

if(condition3>74){
return "0001"
}
if(condition3>59 && ((condition4 == 3) || (condition5 > 30))){
return "0002"
}

}
```

i want to create dynamic conditional statement like

first i have check for all expressions which have condition1==100
then for ((condition2 == 1) || (condition2 == 2) || (condition2 == 3))
then return value according to final condition

it is something like first DFS and then BFS

can some body can give me idea how to check first Depth and then Bredth First in java

Comment: be little clear. looks like you want an answer to a question straight out of some programming contest.

Comment: You need to put your input variables into a single structure, e.g. array or dict, and then express the conditions in data rather than code, using that data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is : You want define very many conditions and change it continous. You need to have a solution for change dynamically expression and define new condition.

There are two solution for dynamic situation such as your case:

1. Using `Rule Engine`. This has very benefit, you can see more information from http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/JavaRule.html
   and you can see its open source implementation from [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines) .
2. Using `Dynamic Language` or `Script Language` and `Script` api.

in  second solution you have several choise. I writing some in following:

- `Groovy`: A complete and wonderful script language. see http://groovy.codehaus.org/
- `Spring Expression Language`: `Spring` solution for calling simple expression. see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html
- `BeanShell`: A simple but wonderful script language.

There are more dynamic language such as `JRuby` that you can see it by simple searching in web.
You can read more information for `Script` api in java from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javascripting1/).

**Edited:**

For sample, you can use `BeanShell Script Language` as follwoing:

First create a file with name `test.bsh` containg blow contents:

```
if(variable_1 == 100 )
{
   System.out.println("Sample condition checked and is true.");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Sample condition checked and is false.");
}
```

Second set `variable_1` from java:

```
import bsh.*;

Interpreter bsh = new Interpreter ();
bsh.set ("variable_1", 100);
```

and in final call script as following:

```
 bsh.source (script);
```

and result will be as following:

```
Sample condition checked and is true.
```

by this approach you can change `test.bsh` content without recompile or restart.